# Restrict some products for specific admin users in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I have a website made in `opencart` what is wanted is to make an admin user that can access and change only Samsung products.

So I'm thinking that a way out can be like something that we assign all Samsung mobile phones a category and give access to that admin user to access only Samsung category of the catalog.

But I really don't know how to do it. 
Please suggest any extension or any code for this.

Comment: Opencart does not provide this kind of functionality. You have to do manually. A better way to make the condition from getting user_id $data['user_id'] = $this->session->data['user_id'].